# Match tag inside tag using bash

Tags: bash, sed, terminal, grep

I have this html

```
<article class="article column large-12 small-12 article--nyheter">
    <a class="article__link" href="/nyheter/14343208/">
            
        <div class="article__content">
            <h2 class="article__title t54 tm24">Person har falt ned bratt terreng - luftambulanse er på vei</h2>
        </div>
    </a>
    
</article>
<article class="article column large-6 small-6 article--nyheter">
    <a class="article__link" href="/nyheter/14341466/">
            <figure class="image image__responsive" style="padding-bottom:42.075%;">

<img class="image__img lazyload" itemprop="image" title="" alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKhI+py+0Po5yUFQA7" />

</figure>
        <div class="article__content">
            <h2 class="article__title t34 tm24">Vil styrke innsatsen mot vold i nære relasjoner</h2>
        </div>
    </a>
    
</article>
```

The thing is that I want to get only those html tags, in this case article tags, which has a child img tag inside them.

I have this sed command

```
sed -n  '/<article class.*article--nyheter/,/<\/article>/p' onlyArticlesWithOutSpace.html > test.html
```

Now what I am trying ti achieve is to get only those article tags which has img tag inside them.

Output I want would be this

```
<article class="article column large-6 small-6 article--nyheter">
    <a class="article__link" href="/nyheter/14341466/">
            <figure class="image image__responsive" style="padding-bottom:42.075%;">

<img class="image__img lazyload" itemprop="image" title="" alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKhI+py+0Po5yUFQA7" />
```

I cannot use any xml/html parser. Just looking to use sed, grep, awk etc.

```
</figure>
        <div class="article__content">
            <h2 class="article__title t34 tm24">Vil styrke innsatsen mot vold i nære relasjoner</h2>
        </div>
    </a>

</article>
```

Comment: `I want to get only those html tags, in this case article tags, which has a child img tag inside them`: `sed` is not the right tool for this. Use a HTML parser in `perl, python or php`.

Comment: Yes I know that but like I mentioned I cannot use anything else then sed, awk, grep

Answer (score 1):

### Care: parsing XML using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) is a wrong good idea!

Thanks to [Cyrus's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/123516816?noredirect=1) for pointing to good reference.

Anyway, U could try this:

```
sed -ne '/<article/{ :a; N; /<\/article/ ! ba ; /<img/p ; }'
```

Comment: Got this error sed: 2: "/<article/{ :a; N; /<\/ ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)

Comment: @mohsinali1317: With your example shown, there is no mistake. This is exactly why you don't use `sed`. Please [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858). I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: @mohsinali1317 Care to use **single** quotes around script. This use GNU `sed`.